# make folder and subfolder in that folder

Tags: php

i want to make a folder with the project id and then i have to make sub folder for that id and in the sub folder i have add two files and two images....
the name for the sub folder is one of the file's name without extension..
how can i do???
my code:
          function add_sub_project_ok()
    {

```
    $i=0;
            $query = $this->main_model->select_project();
            if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data['adv'][$i]['id']=$row->id;
                    $data['adv'][$i]['p_name']=$row->p_name;
                    $data['adv'][$i]['d_link']=base_url().'uploads'.$data['adv'][$i]['id'];
                    $i++;
                }
            }
    $data['p_name']=$this->input->post('pname');

    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];


    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'.$this->db->insert_id().'/';

    $path=$config['upload_path'];

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pjpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '750';
    $config['max_width'] = '1920';
    $config['max_height'] = '1280';
    $this->load->library('upload');



    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!empty($key['name']))
        {
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
    //            flashMsg($errors);
            }
            else
            {
                $temp = $this->_process_pic();

                $data['reg']['FK_add_pname_id']=$data['adv'][$i]['id'];
                $data['reg']['img_name']=$temp['imagename'];
                $data['reg']['img_name_tn']=$temp['thumbnail'];
                $data['reg']['ipa']=$_FILES['ipa']['name'];
                $data['reg']['plist']=$_FILES['plist']['name'];
                $data['reg']['uname']=$_POST['uname'];
                $data['reg']['pass']=$_POST['pass'];
                $this->main_model->update($data['reg'],$id);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->file_upload($data,$id);

}
function file_upload($data,$id)
{
    $data['p_name']=$this->input->post('pname');
    $file_name = $_FILES['ipa']['name'];
    mkdir('uploads/'.$id.'/'.$file_name);
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/'.$id.'/'.$file_name;

    $path=$config['upload_path'];

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'exe|psd|pdf|xls|ppt|php|php4|php3|js|swf|Xhtml|zip|mid|midi|mp2|mp3|wav|html|htm|txt|rtf|mpeg|mpg|avi|doc|docx|xlsx';

    $this->load->library('upload');



    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!empty($key['name']))
        {
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
```

//                    flashMsg($errors);
                }
            }
        }
        redirect('main_con');
    }

```
function _process_pic() {

//Get File Data Info
$uploads = array($this->upload->data());

$this->load->library('image_lib');

//Move Files To User Folder
foreach ($uploads as $key[] => $value) {


$newimagename = url_title($value['raw_name'] . $value['file_ext'], 'underscore');
move_uploaded_file($value['full_path'], '/uploads/' . $newimagename);
//Creat Thumbnail
$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$config['source_image'] = $value['full_path'];
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['thumb_marker'] = '_tn';
$config['master_dim'] = 'width';
$config['quality'] = 75;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 100;
$config['height'] = 100;
$config['new_image'] = $newimagename;


$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

$this->image_lib->resize();
if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();

$filesize = $value['file_size'];
$width = $value['image_width'];
$height = $value['image_height'];
$timestamp = time();
$this->image_lib->clear();
$temp['imagename'] = $value['file_name'];
$temp['thumbnail'] = $value['raw_name'] . '_tn' . $value['file_ext'];
return $temp;
}
```

}

Comment: Code overload! Can you extract just the fragments relating to your problem rather than all of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for a recursive mkdir?

```
@mkdir('uploads/'.$id.'/'.$file_name, 0777, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
 function rmkdir($path) {
        $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path);
        $path = explode("/", $path);

        $rebuild = '';
        foreach($path AS $p) {

            if(strstr($p, ":") != false) { 
                echo "\nExists : in $p\n";
                $rebuild = $p;
                continue;
            }
            $rebuild .= "/$p";
            echo "Checking: $rebuild\n";
            if(!is_dir($rebuild)) mkdir($rebuild);
        }
    }
```